# How to create FTP accounts for each registered user

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ftp-client

I want that when a user sign up on my website, a FTP account will be created for him. So every user can access their folder using File Zilla.

Comment: Giving FTP is bad idea..

Comment: You don't provide enough information. How does a user sign up to your website? What membership provider do you use etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you can create a new ftp user via the command line and use chroot to limit him to a particular directory. And one of the answers at https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line gives you a way to stop 'sudo' from asking you for the password on the command line. Then its purely a matter of building an interface, and invoking system() or exec() to run the commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to tell from your question what exactly you want to do. This is a very complex subject that involves a lot of work you need to do in order to achieve this.

If you are using an asp.net custom membership provider you can create the folder there(for example).

Then you need to create a custom authentication provider for IIS which is not an easy task on it's own. Check out [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/598/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-a-simple-ftp-authentication-provider/) and [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/669/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-authentication-provider-using-an-xml-database/) blog posts from Robert McMurray. This module will use your user data in your database that you fill in with the custom membership provider.

Then finally you need to provide each user access to his/her own folder trough user isolation in FTP in IIS.